# Prevent direct access Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla

i built my site in Joomla 2.5 with xampp for win7.
I have a module password  that provides access at the standard Joomla's registration form if the guest gives the right password, but there is a problem, if the user put the link 
localhost/joomla/index.php/el/?option=com_users&view=registration in a new tab, avoid the password. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy,
just go to the backend and select:

Users -> Users manager -> Options -> Allow User Registration -> Νο

Then users are not able to register.